# React Native TTS error TextToSpeech is undefined

Tags: react-native, text-to-speech

I did the 2 setup steps including linking,

still

```
import Tts from 'react-native-tts';
Tts.setDefaultLanguage('de-DE');
```

yeilds an exception

tried getInitStatus(), throws the same exception

```
TextToSpeech is undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to rebuild the app through gradle

react-native run-android